# Как сделать полосу прогресса

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу добавить себе на сайт полосу прогресса (не знаю как правильно называется) Допустим есть простейший текстовый сайт. Нужно добавить наверх сайта (с позицией `fixed`) тонкую полосу (толщиной в примерно 5-10 пикселей) которая при прокрутке сайта вниз будет заполняться, а при прокрутке вверх - убывать.

```html
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>A Great Demo on CodePen</title>
</head>
<body>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer orci augue, fringilla nec molestie id, imperdiet in nisi. Quisque mauris leo, ornare ac urna sollicitudin, posuere accumsan dui. Nulla facilisi. Nam sed dui nec orci euismod finibus id quis justo. Ut et ornare nisi, sit amet tincidunt sem. Donec blandit interdum est tempor mattis. Maecenas in nisi mauris. Proin dignissim turpis vel nisl commodo pretium. Curabitur condimentum massa sed suscipit aliquam. Cras elementum auctor sapien quis sollicitudin. Sed in tincidunt mi.

Vivamus sodales ex non nunc fermentum, sed scelerisque risus tincidunt. Nunc gravida sem a enim sollicitudin pulvinar. Cras sit amet diam nulla. Etiam consequat urna at feugiat tristique. Sed eu placerat massa. Quisque in fringilla nibh, non porta ex. Quisque rhoncus maximus lorem, ut suscipit dui laoreet ac. Suspendisse et luctus eros. Nullam dapibus tempus tempus. Quisque a libero sed est tincidunt efficitur eu sed mi. Proin bibendum quam arcu, at efficitur lorem molestie in. Vestibulum consequat, erat non porta aliquam, sem magna bibendum arcu, ac lobortis ex sapien in metus. Donec porttitor odio ac tristique tempor. Etiam id tellus tempor, consectetur arcu ut, gravida leo. Nunc at quam mattis, volutpat massa ut, mattis urna. Maecenas ut luctus enim, eu lacinia odio.

In quis lorem condimentum, ornare dui et, euismod neque. Nunc ut nisi sit amet est blandit rhoncus nec ac felis. Sed at purus maximus, facilisis arcu quis, mollis ante. Nam in dui a orci fermentum iaculis et condimentum nunc. Nullam venenatis in elit sed gravida. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam non volutpat dui. Sed lacinia tellus ac ex congue, eget hendrerit dui tempus. Phasellus ornare urna turpis, sit amet dictum massa lobortis ut.

Fusce commodo efficitur purus a tincidunt. Quisque nec tellus ex. Nam viverra est vel mollis tincidunt. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec facilisis facilisis sapien, eu euismod mauris suscipit sit amet. Aliquam in nisl faucibus, varius lorem vel, accumsan nunc. Aliquam eu quam mollis, luctus neque eget, lobortis lacus. Morbi eleifend justo a lacus dignissim, a consequat leo porta. Nunc sit amet pharetra erat. Fusce sit amet ex at lectus porttitor aliquet vitae vel tellus. Quisque consectetur, est ut fermentum laoreet, lorem sem ultricies mauris, ut sollicitudin lorem massa sed sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

Etiam porttitor placerat lacinia. Aenean non sollicitudin ex, eu finibus neque. Aenean a mauris maximus, commodo ante ac, ultricies leo. Duis dapibus ligula sodales aliquet vulputate. Curabitur nec urna ut ante pulvinar consequat. Proin ut est urna. Aenean fringilla felis a augue convallis, sodales rhoncus lacus ultricies. Nam euismod dolor id lorem auctor, in volutpat orci aliquet. Fusce laoreet luctus ante, a posuere sem tincidunt nec. Mauris nec quam sed felis placerat posuere. Donec vehicula, dolor a scelerisque hendrerit, felis nunc tincidunt urna, faucibus imperdiet leo augue sit amet neque.

Nam eros augue, malesuada et hendrerit ut, feugiat ut eros. Nullam et iaculis magna. Donec at ultrices justo. Sed non felis sit amet dui molestie suscipit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed nec leo ac augue dignissim fermentum vel tincidunt diam. Etiam elementum, augue id pulvinar pretium, lacus ex molestie ante, eu aliquam elit velit sed purus. Phasellus viverra felis velit, sit amet semper sem consectetur at. Nulla euismod nisi sed neque laoreet, at porta risus ullamcorper. Vivamus accumsan neque porta libero efficitur rutrum. Donec nunc augue, faucibus vitae scelerisque a, faucibus non dolor. Curabitur aliquet aliquam enim, nec maximus orci.

Sed finibus, tortor vel laoreet sodales, diam metus maximus lacus, id tincidunt augue diam ut nisl. Nullam eget tincidunt enim. Pellentesque vel aliquam elit, eget sagittis ligula. Fusce ac dolor mattis, gravida orci ac, blandit lacus. Praesent ac nunc feugiat, volutpat tortor eget, pulvinar turpis. Sed vitae vehicula magna. Quisque eu ex at nisl lacinia gravida. Sed id faucibus ante. Sed risus sapien, pulvinar id nisl et, scelerisque hendrerit lectus. Aenean aliquet justo non nunc congue, non dignissim metus maximus. Aliquam dolor est, vestibulum nec mauris vitae, sollicitudin eleifend nulla.

Duis vitae tincidunt eros. Donec elit odio, accumsan vitae libero at, vestibulum ultrices nulla. Nunc elementum urna eget est elementum, vitae aliquet turpis egestas. Curabitur aliquet elit dapibus tristique scelerisque. Suspendisse porttitor enim eget arcu fringilla placerat. Curabitur mattis eget augue viverra finibus. Aliquam et diam placerat, iaculis diam sit amet, hendrerit sem. Proin ullamcorper id enim sed suscipit. Maecenas id velit at eros congue feugiat sed at elit. Integer laoreet lacus dolor, sit amet ornare tortor ullamcorper eget. Etiam tortor libero, feugiat ut posuere ut, sagittis sed leo. Mauris tincidunt maximus sodales. Phasellus at augue aliquam, posuere dui sed, aliquam leo.

Etiam vitae tincidunt turpis. Vestibulum et est accumsan arcu rutrum tempus in vitae dui. Vivamus varius auctor mi, vitae mattis urna sollicitudin non. Praesent eu dolor id diam ultricies lobortis quis accumsan ligula. In vel risus ac neque venenatis euismod. Sed ultrices dui in placerat lobortis. Praesent eu nisl eros. Sed ac nisl commodo, posuere eros quis, consequat est. In at lorem ac nulla sodales lacinia ut eget lectus.

Pellentesque id felis quis orci aliquam eleifend. Duis ultrices neque vel semper varius. Pellentesque eleifend bibendum tincidunt. Nulla sodales scelerisque ex, at tempus ex congue nec. Donec congue ullamcorper est et varius. Sed ligula risus, faucibus finibus ipsum ut, fringilla lobortis augue. Proin ac est et ligula congue dapibus. Nulla maximus ullamcorper risus in vulputate. Nunc facilisis ac tortor quis cursus. Praesent ante odio, dapibus eu finibus ut, ultricies in turpis. Aenean mollis eros nec eros volutpat aliquam a nec justo. Donec lobortis eros ultricies, aliquam diam nec, dignissim magna. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse potenti.

Mauris mauris justo, malesuada sit amet sollicitudin id, viverra sed sapien. Aliquam egestas eget erat id rutrum. Sed ligula arcu, sodales vitae pellentesque sit amet, lacinia vitae nibh. Donec a nisi ut eros posuere semper. Praesent magna justo, dapibus eu tincidunt et, tincidunt eget sem. Quisque tincidunt fermentum metus eu mollis. Quisque ac neque quis mauris dapibus pretium.

Vestibulum efficitur quam ac tortor ultricies congue. Praesent non volutpat nibh. Suspendisse potenti. Cras magna tortor, hendrerit non mi a, rhoncus tincidunt mauris. Nullam sed erat vel dui mollis viverra et a metus. Nulla semper justo id rutrum condimentum. Morbi rutrum rhoncus enim nec iaculis. Duis dictum risus ante, cursus tincidunt orci consequat nec. Nunc aliquam malesuada dui, rutrum pellentesque dui mattis nec. Donec posuere tellus nec nunc ultrices aliquet. Donec ullamcorper, felis ut gravida gravida, sem ex cursus purus, at suscipit leo nibh ut tellus. Duis luctus, nulla vel placerat pellentesque, mi diam hendrerit tortor, id maximus sapien nisi at tellus. Nullam feugiat tortor vitae iaculis ultricies.

Cras congue suscipit diam, vel posuere massa consectetur sit amet. Aenean pretium tellus eget felis ultrices, quis commodo diam faucibus. Maecenas pellentesque sodales tristique. Proin aliquet ipsum non tincidunt blandit. Vestibulum tristique elementum congue. Sed malesuada leo at pharetra tempus. Ut consequat mauris neque, ut faucibus leo interdum vitae. Donec aliquet tempor magna, ultricies pulvinar enim tristique dictum.

Nullam quis massa vitae elit bibendum feugiat vitae id erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent gravida odio laoreet odio congue, et posuere ex mattis. Aenean suscipit vitae lacus sit amet semper. Aenean iaculis laoreet justo commodo maximus. Nam quis dictum nibh. In porttitor mi turpis, vel malesuada metus consectetur in. Integer quis aliquet mi. Aliquam vitae nibh vitae odio ullamcorper egestas et nec neque. Suspendisse ac velit a enim pulvinar finibus in id tortor. Nam lacinia sem eu mattis interdum. Nam faucibus quis turpis a tristique.

Phasellus ut ante at orci efficitur scelerisque. Pellentesque ultrices nunc in sapien vestibulum feugiat. In lorem est, auctor in nisl vel, aliquet auctor ante. In sed est et justo molestie egestas. Suspendisse non urna eget odio convallis convallis. In a risus finibus, sollicitudin arcu a, mattis est. Mauris eu velit pellentesque, bibendum lorem ac, auctor risus. Morbi fringilla in nibh in aliquet.
  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer orci augue, fringilla nec molestie id, imperdiet in nisi. Quisque mauris leo, ornare ac urna sollicitudin, posuere accumsan dui. Nulla facilisi. Nam sed dui nec orci euismod finibus id quis justo. Ut et ornare nisi, sit amet tincidunt sem. Donec blandit interdum est tempor mattis. Maecenas in nisi mauris. Proin dignissim turpis vel nisl commodo pretium. Curabitur condimentum massa sed suscipit aliquam. Cras elementum auctor sapien quis sollicitudin. Sed in tincidunt mi.

Vivamus sodales ex non nunc fermentum, sed scelerisque risus tincidunt. Nunc gravida sem a enim sollicitudin pulvinar. Cras sit amet diam nulla. Etiam consequat urna at feugiat tristique. Sed eu placerat massa. Quisque in fringilla nibh, non porta ex. Quisque rhoncus maximus lorem, ut suscipit dui laoreet ac. Suspendisse et luctus eros. Nullam dapibus tempus tempus. Quisque a libero sed est tincidunt efficitur eu sed mi. Proin bibendum quam arcu, at efficitur lorem molestie in. Vestibulum consequat, erat non porta aliquam, sem magna bibendum arcu, ac lobortis ex sapien in metus. Donec porttitor odio ac tristique tempor. Etiam id tellus tempor, consectetur arcu ut, gravida leo. Nunc at quam mattis, volutpat massa ut, mattis urna. Maecenas ut luctus enim, eu lacinia odio.

In quis lorem condimentum, ornare dui et, euismod neque. Nunc ut nisi sit amet est blandit rhoncus nec ac felis. Sed at purus maximus, facilisis arcu quis, mollis ante. Nam in dui a orci fermentum iaculis et condimentum nunc. Nullam venenatis in elit sed gravida. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam non volutpat dui. Sed lacinia tellus ac ex congue, eget hendrerit dui tempus. Phasellus ornare urna turpis, sit amet dictum massa lobortis ut.

Fusce commodo efficitur purus a tincidunt. Quisque nec tellus ex. Nam viverra est vel mollis tincidunt. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec facilisis facilisis sapien, eu euismod mauris suscipit sit amet. Aliquam in nisl faucibus, varius lorem vel, accumsan nunc. Aliquam eu quam mollis, luctus neque eget, lobortis lacus. Morbi eleifend justo a lacus dignissim, a consequat leo porta. Nunc sit amet pharetra erat. Fusce sit amet ex at lectus porttitor aliquet vitae vel tellus. Quisque consectetur, est ut fermentum laoreet, lorem sem ultricies mauris, ut sollicitudin lorem massa sed sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

Etiam porttitor placerat lacinia. Aenean non sollicitudin ex, eu finibus neque. Aenean a mauris maximus, commodo ante ac, ultricies leo. Duis dapibus ligula sodales aliquet vulputate. Curabitur nec urna ut ante pulvinar consequat. Proin ut est urna. Aenean fringilla felis a augue convallis, sodales rhoncus lacus ultricies. Nam euismod dolor id lorem auctor, in volutpat orci aliquet. Fusce laoreet luctus ante, a posuere sem tincidunt nec. Mauris nec quam sed felis placerat posuere. Donec vehicula, dolor a scelerisque hendrerit, felis nunc tincidunt urna, faucibus imperdiet leo augue sit amet neque.

Nam eros augue, malesuada et hendrerit ut, feugiat ut eros. Nullam et iaculis magna. Donec at ultrices justo. Sed non felis sit amet dui molestie suscipit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed nec leo ac augue dignissim fermentum vel tincidunt diam. Etiam elementum, augue id pulvinar pretium, lacus ex molestie ante, eu aliquam elit velit sed purus. Phasellus viverra felis velit, sit amet semper sem consectetur at. Nulla euismod nisi sed neque laoreet, at porta risus ullamcorper. Vivamus accumsan neque porta libero efficitur rutrum. Donec nunc augue, faucibus vitae scelerisque a, faucibus non dolor. Curabitur aliquet aliquam enim, nec maximus orci.

Sed finibus, tortor vel laoreet sodales, diam metus maximus lacus, id tincidunt augue diam ut nisl. Nullam eget tincidunt enim. Pellentesque vel aliquam elit, eget sagittis ligula. Fusce ac dolor mattis, gravida orci ac, blandit lacus. Praesent ac nunc feugiat, volutpat tortor eget, pulvinar turpis. Sed vitae vehicula magna. Quisque eu ex at nisl lacinia gravida. Sed id faucibus ante. Sed risus sapien, pulvinar id nisl et, scelerisque hendrerit lectus. Aenean aliquet justo non nunc congue, non dignissim metus maximus. Aliquam dolor est, vestibulum nec mauris vitae, sollicitudin eleifend nulla.

Duis vitae tincidunt eros. Donec elit odio, accumsan vitae libero at, vestibulum ultrices nulla. Nunc elementum urna eget est elementum, vitae aliquet turpis egestas. Curabitur aliquet elit dapibus tristique scelerisque. Suspendisse porttitor enim eget arcu fringilla placerat. Curabitur mattis eget augue viverra finibus. Aliquam et diam placerat, iaculis diam sit amet, hendrerit sem. Proin ullamcorper id enim sed suscipit. Maecenas id velit at eros congue feugiat sed at elit. Integer laoreet lacus dolor, sit amet ornare tortor ullamcorper eget. Etiam tortor libero, feugiat ut posuere ut, sagittis sed leo. Mauris tincidunt maximus sodales. Phasellus at augue aliquam, posuere dui sed, aliquam leo.

Etiam vitae tincidunt turpis. Vestibulum et est accumsan arcu rutrum tempus in vitae dui. Vivamus varius auctor mi, vitae mattis urna sollicitudin non. Praesent eu dolor id diam ultricies lobortis quis accumsan ligula. In vel risus ac neque venenatis euismod. Sed ultrices dui in placerat lobortis. Praesent eu nisl eros. Sed ac nisl commodo, posuere eros quis, consequat est. In at lorem ac nulla sodales lacinia ut eget lectus.

Pellentesque id felis quis orci aliquam eleifend. Duis ultrices neque vel semper varius. Pellentesque eleifend bibendum tincidunt. Nulla sodales scelerisque ex, at tempus ex congue nec. Donec congue ullamcorper est et varius. Sed ligula risus, faucibus finibus ipsum ut, fringilla lobortis augue. Proin ac est et ligula congue dapibus. Nulla maximus ullamcorper risus in vulputate. Nunc facilisis ac tortor quis cursus. Praesent ante odio, dapibus eu finibus ut, ultricies in turpis. Aenean mollis eros nec eros volutpat aliquam a nec justo. Donec lobortis eros ultricies, aliquam diam nec, dignissim magna. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse potenti.

Mauris mauris justo, malesuada sit amet sollicitudin id, viverra sed sapien. Aliquam egestas eget erat id rutrum. Sed ligula arcu, sodales vitae pellentesque sit amet, lacinia vitae nibh. Donec a nisi ut eros posuere semper. Praesent magna justo, dapibus eu tincidunt et, tincidunt eget sem. Quisque tincidunt fermentum metus eu mollis. Quisque ac neque quis mauris dapibus pretium.

Vestibulum efficitur quam ac tortor ultricies congue. Praesent non volutpat nibh. Suspendisse potenti. Cras magna tortor, hendrerit non mi a, rhoncus tincidunt mauris. Nullam sed erat vel dui mollis viverra et a metus. Nulla semper justo id rutrum condimentum. Morbi rutrum rhoncus enim nec iaculis. Duis dictum risus ante, cursus tincidunt orci consequat nec. Nunc aliquam malesuada dui, rutrum pellentesque dui mattis nec. Donec posuere tellus nec nunc ultrices aliquet. Donec ullamcorper, felis ut gravida gravida, sem ex cursus purus, at suscipit leo nibh ut tellus. Duis luctus, nulla vel placerat pellentesque, mi diam hendrerit tortor, id maximus sapien nisi at tellus. Nullam feugiat tortor vitae iaculis ultricies.

Cras congue suscipit diam, vel posuere massa consectetur sit amet. Aenean pretium tellus eget felis ultrices, quis commodo diam faucibus. Maecenas pellentesque sodales tristique. Proin aliquet ipsum non tincidunt blandit. Vestibulum tristique elementum congue. Sed malesuada leo at pharetra tempus. Ut consequat mauris neque, ut faucibus leo interdum vitae. Donec aliquet tempor magna, ultricies pulvinar enim tristique dictum.

Nullam quis massa vitae elit bibendum feugiat vitae id erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent gravida odio laoreet odio congue, et posuere ex mattis. Aenean suscipit vitae lacus sit amet semper. Aenean iaculis laoreet justo commodo maximus. Nam quis dictum nibh. In porttitor mi turpis, vel malesuada metus consectetur in. Integer quis aliquet mi. Aliquam vitae nibh vitae odio ullamcorper egestas et nec neque. Suspendisse ac velit a enim pulvinar finibus in id tortor. Nam lacinia sem eu mattis interdum. Nam faucibus quis turpis a tristique.

Phasellus ut ante at orci efficitur scelerisque. Pellentesque ultrices nunc in sapien vestibulum feugiat. In lorem est, auctor in nisl vel, aliquet auctor ante. In sed est et justo molestie egestas. Suspendisse non urna eget odio convallis convallis. In a risus finibus, sollicitudin arcu a, mattis est. Mauris eu velit pellentesque, bibendum lorem ac, auctor risus. Morbi fringilla in nibh in aliquet.
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  max-width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }
```

Comment: [Пример](https://html5css.ru/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.php)

Comment: @Kirill: зачем здесь эта ссылка без вашего ответа?

Comment: @UModeL: оформлять ответ ради одной ссылки?

Comment: @Kirill: зачем давать такую ссылку? Чтобы человек ушёл по ней, оставив вопрос незакрытым и забыл про него? Зачем Вы гадите сообществу? Может сразу тогда сделать автоматический редирект на Гугл?

Comment: @Kirill Спасибо !

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Когда происходит скролл - вызывется функция
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction();
};

function myFunction() {
  const winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  const height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  const scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.header h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: #4caf50;
  width: 0%;
}

.content {
  padding: 100px 0;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <h2>Scroll Indicator</h2>
    <div class="progress-container">
      <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h3>Scroll Down to See The Effect</h3>
    <p>We have created a "progress bar" to <b>show how far a page has been scrolled</b>.</p>
    <p>It also <b>works when you scroll back up</b>.</p>
    <p>It is even <b>responsive</b>! Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Источник**: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp